# "started as designer and supplier of " VS "started as the designer and supplier of "

Tags: articles

About the [overview of a company](https://www.moog.com/about-us.html#), I see:

> 1. Over fifty years ago, we started as designer and supplier of aircraft and missile components.

Would it more gramatically correct if we say:

> 2. Over fifty years ago, we started as **the** designer and supplier of aircraft and missile components.

Answer (score 4):

No, it would not be more correct, because using "the" would imply that the company was the only or the predominant designer. That was hardly the case.

I would use the indefinite article there.

> Over fifty years ago, we started as **a** designer and supplier of aircraft and missile components.